# Using the Nvidia Graphic card in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm new to ubuntu and i've been having this question since the day i installed Ubuntu. Does ubuntu come along with the necessary drivers for my Nvidia 640M graphic card? Also , My computer was overheating a few months back and i found out that the problem was with the Nvidia Optimus thing so i had to use Bumblebee and disable the graphic card. So, everytime i need to use my gc, i type  *$ optirun applicationname* and that enables my gc again . So, do i need to install my Nvidia drivers for my graphic card and if yes, how ? Any help is appreciated. thanks in advance !  :)

Answer (score 0):

Install Driver packages for Video Card :

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

If not resolved reconfigure the drivers:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg
```

Answer (score 0):

I had endless problems with the nvidia drivers that are available from ubuntu.

My problem was sorted when i with adding the follwoing repository's

*for nvidia drivers;*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

*for bumblebee;*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
```

*then update;*

```
sudo apt-get update
```

*Then install the nvidia-319 nvidia divers and bumblebee (these will bring in the latest nvidia drivers required)*

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia nvidia-319 nvidia-settings-319 virtualgl
```

Reboot and should be working.